# can't connect to wireless after set static ip

Tags: wireless, static-ip, wpa-supplicant

i'm using ubuntu 16.04 and i was not able to see wifi options in gui,then it suddenly change the wifi wave icon to this **↑↓** icon.Then i decided to set static ip for it by modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces`.When i had rebooted my computer,it's losing the connection and can't do any authorising function.please help me to fix this,i 'm starting tired of ubuntu.

Comment: You can set static IP in Network Manager. Adding an interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` disables Network Manager. You need to chose which way you want to setup Wi-Fi. You can't connect using NM and set IP in `interfaces`.

Comment: thank,i don't actually understand much about nm and how that system works,so now i need to delete the data in interface file?

Comment: Remove everything you added to the file and setup your interface by clicking the NM icon.